# Microsoft Azure Java SDK: snapshot copy

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am looking for a way to copy azure managed disk snapshots between regions using Java SDK. Any suggestions or pointers will be helpful

Thanks in advance
Prasad

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java SDK to create Azure managed disk snapshots with different resource groups and regions:

```
Disk osDisk = azure.disks().getById(linuxVM.osDiskId());
Snapshot osSnapshot = azure.snapshots().define(managedOSSnapshotName)
  .withRegion(Region.US_EAST)
  .withExistingResourceGroup(rgName)
  .withLinuxFromDisk(osDisk)
  .create();
```

See [Java: Manage Azure Managed Disks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/java-manage-azure-managed-disks/) to get more details.

**Update-1**

If you want to copy the snapshot from other regions, just change the `withLinuxFromDisk()` into `withLinuxFromSnapshot()`.

You can get more interfaces about Azure snapshot in Java SDK from [Java SDK for Azure](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/18e9a4b927fafc64349de742ccd2f546da9c653b/archive/azure-mgmt-compute/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/Snapshot.java).

**Update-2**

For your issue that you want to create a snapshot from a snapshot. With the code example below and it works well.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.management.Azure;
import com.microsoft.azure.credentials.ApplicationTokenCredentials;
import com.microsoft.azure.AzureEnvironment;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.Snapshot;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.fluentcore.arm.Region;

import java.io.IOException;


public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(
                "xxxxxxxxx",
                "xxxxxxxxx",
                "xxxxxxxxx",
                AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

        Azure.Authenticated azureAuth = Azure.authenticate(credentials);
        Azure azure = azureAuth.withDefaultSubscription();

        Snapshot osSnapshot = azure.snapshots().define("managedOSSnapshotName")
                .withRegion(Region.US_EAST)
                .withExistingResourceGroup("charlesJava")
                .withDataFromSnapshot("/subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/groupName/providers/Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/snapshottest")
                .create();
    }
}
```

The parameter that the `.withDataFromSnapshot()` is the resource Id, in other words, it's the snapshot resource Id. But first of all, you should get **the authentication of the resource group** which you want to use with at least Contributor permission. For this step, you can create a service principal and add the role for your resource group which the snapshot in.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your response. Is there a way to copy existing snapshot to a different region ?

Comment: I am using this as I am trying to copy a data snapshot:                            `Snapshot snap = azure.snapshots().getById(snapshotId);     
            Snapshot snapCopy = azure.snapshots().define(label)
                    .withRegion(getRegionAsAzureRegion(region))
                    .withExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
                    .withDataFromSnapshot(snap)
                    .create();`

Comment: But the create API fails with:  Azure error - Resorce <Snapshot name> is not found.

Comment: Why do you want to create a snapshot from the snapshot? And do you check if the snapshot exists or you get the real snapshot id or use the right API? I do not know what you really want.

Comment: Hi - I am using 2 VMs in 2 different regions running MySQL replication. I take backup snapshots for mysql data only for the first VM that is running in WEST US. Now I want to restore one of the mysql data snapshots to the VM running in EAST US and hence trying to copy this snapshot from WEST US. Yes, Snapshot is a valid snapshot with a valid snapshot id. I hope the use case is clear. I have also tried taking snapshot directly from the disk from another region. That fails as well.. Any idea if this API is tested and supported ? Thanks  a lot for your help.

Comment: I am using  "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/SG-azureeast/providers/Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/SG-myX7-945-2018-10-11-11-10-42" as a parameter to  withDataFromSnapshot().  But it still fails with the error: 'com.microsoft.azure.CloudException: Resource SG-myX7-945-2018-10-11-11-10-42 is not found.: Resource SG-myX7-945-2018-10-11-11-10-42 is not found.
 at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient.createExceptionFromResponse(AzureClient.java:740)
 at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient.access$100(AzureClient.java:33)
 at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient$3.call(AzureClient.java:160)'

Comment: Do you get the authentication of the resource group which you use?

Comment: Yes we do. Can you confirm if you are able to copy snapshots across regions using the above code or you are copying snapshots within the same region ?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I try it and cannot copy a snapshot in different regions even if the Azure CLI. It seems we cannot achieve it.

Comment: Is this a bug or new request ? Also are there any workarounds ?

Comment: I'm not clear about that. Maybe you can create a snapshot from disk to new regions. You can add your issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues).